# Getting between Melbourne's Tullamarine and Avalon airports?

Tags: public-transport, melbourne, mel, avv

A friend is going to be needing to get from one of Melbourne's airports to the other.  There doesn't seem to be any direct transfer.  Is there a method (other than taxi) to get from one to the other, or will he need to Skybus into Southern Cross station and out again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct transfer, Avalon gets only a few flights a day and nobody books connecting flights between the two on purpose.

The only remotely sane non-taxi option is to take the [Sunbus](http://www.sitacoaches.com.au/avalon/) from Avalon to Southern Cross (adult $22), and then switch to the [Skybus](http://www.skybus.com.au/) to Tullamarine ($18).

If you're really pinching pennies, there are zero public transport alternatives for Avalon, but it's possible to take a train from Southern Cross to Broadmeadows and switch to an occasional bus for the price of a normal Zone 2 ticket.  This takes approximately forever though, and Broadmeadows is not the most savoury place in Melbourne to hang out at night.  Details on [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Melbourne_Airport#Ground_transportation).

Last and least, a taxi from Avalon to Tulla would be well north of $100, but given the cost of the bus this might actually make sense for a group of three or more.

Answer (score 1):

Take taxi from Avalon Airport to Lara Railway Station and from there take [V/ Line](http://www.vline.com.au/home/) Regional train to Footscray Rail Station. From there take Metro train with direction Williamstown and stop at North Melbourne Railway Station, platform 5. Go to platform 2 and take Metro train with direction Craigieburn to Broadmeadows Station, platform 2. Then take [Bus Route 901](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/route/view/7531) that will drop you in front of Melbourne International Airport / Tullamarine

Comment: North Melbourne is direction City from Footscray, not Williamstown.  Also, that's four transfers and something like three hours even if your schedules line up...!

Comment: Good research in this answer. The OP should note that you'll need a myki card to travel on the PTV network, which *should* be obtainable at the Lara station, but the machines do break down frequently so you may like to order one online in advance.